# Clean abnormally terminated spring batch job

Tags: spring-batch, instance

Our Spring Batch job failed abruptly while processing an input file.
When i'm trying to rerun the batch job, its throwing the below message.

*02:27:09.088 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.c.r.dao.JdbcStepExecutionDao - Truncating long message before update of StepExecution, original message is: org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Cannot restart step from STARTING status.  The old execution may still be executing, so you may need to verify manually that this is the case.*

I know that if spring batch job fails abnormally then rewards_job_execution, batch_job_execution and batch_step_execution table wont get the proper status and end_time.

Is there any successful approach to complete/finish the current instance and start a new one?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing within Spring Batch that will do that type of cleanup.  The main reason is that typically the decision of what to do (Is the execution `FAILED`?  Is it `COMPLETE`?  Is it something else?) is typically a human decision at the job level.  You'll need to handle the cleanup yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael.  For a time being, i have renamed the input file and rerun the job.

Answer (score 0):

You should use skiplistener.
To reslove this

Comment: Thanks pdubey.  Will try and let you know.